# What is the meaning of "E-value" in the BLAST search?

Tags: proteins, sequence-alignment, blast

After reading many pages, I still do not understand the definition. Can someone use simple words to explain me that?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST
This expectation or expect value "E" (often called an E score or E-value or e-value) assessing the significance of the HSP score for un-gapped local alignment is reported in the BLAST results.

If a lower E value means closer results to the query sequence, what is its difference to "Sequence Identity Cutoff"? http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/search/advSearch.do?search=new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the definition [here](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=FAQ):

> the number of hits one can "expect" to see by chance when searching a
>   database of a particular size.

Also read some of the background information given to understand the meaning:

> It decreases exponentially as the Score
>   (S) of the match increases. Essentially, the E value describes the
>   random background noise. For example, an E value of 1 assigned to a
>   hit can be interpreted as meaning that in a database of the current
>   size one might expect to see 1 match with a similar score simply by
>   chance. The lower the E-value, or the closer it is to zero, the more
>   "significant" the match is. However, keep in mind that virtually
>   identical short alignments have relatively high E values. This is
>   because the calculation of the E value takes into account the length
>   of the query sequence. These high E values make sense because shorter
>   sequences have a higher probability of occurring in the database
>   purely by chance. For more details please see the calculations in the
>   BLAST Course. The Expect value can also be used as a convenient way to
>   create a significance threshold for reporting results. You can change
>   the Expect value threshold on most BLAST search pages. When the Expect
>   value is increased from the default value of 10, a larger list with
>   more low-scoring hits can be reported.

If you want to understand the calculation I would highly recommend to read the [BLAST course](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/Altschul-1.html)

**Update**
Identity is ***not*** the same as the E value
I would try to explain this as easy as possible so let's suppose a sequence:

```
query sequence: ATGCCGTGC
```

When you BLAST this (of course your sequence is much longer), you can get the sequence ATGCCGTGC, which will result in 100% identity (**NOTE** most of the time when you have 100% identity, you have the right sequence but I just picked 100% to make the difference clear. When you have lower percentages of identity the E value is much more important. So when you have 70% identity in different matches e.g. it is important to look a the E value to decide which match is the "right" one for your purpose), now you probably would think that's nice that's the sequence I was looking for. However this would be a mistake! Maybe this sequence is present many times in the database and this is just a random match, this is the point were the E value comes in. Looking at the E value this would be pretty high because you have a short sequence and the chance of matching this in a big database is really high so you can get an E value of let's say: 10. What this means is that you have a chance of finding 10 matches by chance when searching a database of a the current size in other words this match would probably be random! So it's much better to conclude if a match is "significant" based on the E value cut-off than on the identity. Further the choice of the E value is completely yours as said by [WYSIWYG♦](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/3340/wysiwyg) as answer to [a cut-off question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19338/what-e-value-blast-cut-off-is-best/19655#19655):

> E-value refers to the expected number of random hits for a given
>   alignment score. Smaller it is more reliable is your match. There is
>   no hard and fast rule for e-value cutoff. You can keep whatever you
>   want depending on the level of stringency that you require. But you
>   should note that for smaller sequences (< 30nt) there is always a
>   higher likelihood of random matches. In such cases it is practical to
>   relax the e-value cutoff.

**Short simple example**
[image]
Both of these sequences got the same identity but a different E value. What does this mean? Both of the sequences match the same *amount*(57%) of the amino acids however based on the E value you can say just as you said that the first match is *less* likely to be a false positive. I want to note one thing: *Always take a look at the biological significance of your result*. E.g. you extract proteins from a red blood cell and find proteins with a high E value for red blood cell proteins and a low E value for proteins from nerve cells. It's clear that despite the high E value the red blood cells are probably more *biologically significant*.

Comment: I re-edited the question. I feel that "E-Value Cutoff" and "Sequence Identity Cutoff" are the same? Also to clarify, the "hit" means the resulting sequences by BLAST? I think I do not need to know the details of the algorithm. I just want to know how the set the threshhold.

Comment: yes the hits are just the result sequences of BLAST, I updated my answer to clarify the difference between identity and the E value @ianselibai

Comment: thank you so much! I think I understand most of it. So it reduces the random hits. In that case, the lower of the E-value, the less likely for the "false positive" hits.

Comment: It doesn't really reduces the hits but it helps to make a choice about the significance of the hit, just as you said if the E value is low it's less likely that this match is a false positive. So in simple terms: the E value scales your score (based on identity and other factors) so that you can compare this to the other matches. I added a little example in my answer hopefully that will make it clear!

Comment: Sure, so for your "Short simple example", I guess, the first one is shorter than the second one?

Comment: I just closed the result but that's what you would expect indeed! However there are other scaling factors which can influence this but for that you should read the BLAST course

Comment: Sure, I use E-value = 0 to search, still can get hundreds of hits. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: If you want to restrict the matches you can try to use other scoring matrices and other parameters.

Comment: On the RCSB website, I can only increase the "Sequence Identity Cutoff".

Comment: try to use the offical BLAST: https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi But you need to search some information about the paramters if you want to change these

Comment: sure, temporarily I will use RCSB